# $\int\sin(at)\sin(bt)/(t(x-t))dt$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to integrate the above function, where $a$, $b$, and $x$ are constants. I have tried integrating by parts (after using trig formulas to simplify the product), but I run into trouble when I have to select $u$ or $dv$ for the denominator. The antiderivative of $t(x-t)$ gives a logarithm, so I end up needing to integrate a trig function times a logarithm, which is even messier than what I began with.

A $u$-substitution $u = x-t$ right off the bat doesn't appear to help either, as it doesn't change the problem with the denominator.

I have read that functions of this form can be solved using Fourier transforms, however I am not well-versed in this topic.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Answer (score 1):

The result is based on standard sine and cosine integrals (Si and Ci):

$$\frac{-\cos (x (a-b)) \text{Ci}(-(a-b) (t-x))+\cos (x (a+b)) \text{Ci}(-(a+b)
   (t-x))+\text{Ci}((a-b) t)-\text{Ci}((a+b) t)+\sin (x (a-b)) \text{Si}((a-b)
   (t-x))-\sin (x (a+b)) \text{Si}((a+b) (t-x))}{2 x}$$

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that
$$\sin(at)\sin(bt)=\frac 12 \big(\cos((a-b)t)-\cos((a+b)t)\big)$$
$$\frac{1}{t (x-t)}=\frac 1x \big(\frac 1 t-\frac 1 {t-x} \big)$$ That is to say that, if
$$I=\int \frac{\sin(at)\sin(bt)}{t (x-t)}\,dt$$ $2x I$ is the sum of four integrals of the type
$$J=\int \frac{\cos(\alpha t)}{t-\beta}\,dt$$ Let $t=\beta+\frac y \alpha$ to make
$$J=\int \frac{\cos(\alpha t)}{t-\beta}\,dt=\int\frac{\cos (\alpha  \beta +y)}{y}\,dy$$ $$J= \cos (\alpha  \beta )\int \frac{\cos (y)}{y}\,dy-\sin (\alpha  \beta )\int\frac{\sin (y) }{y}\,dy$$
$$J=\cos (\alpha  \beta )\,\text{Ci}(y) -\sin (\alpha  \beta )\,\text{Si}(y) $$